# Error while converting `undefined` to `map<string, AnonymousModel>`

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm trying to create a super simple nested store with mobx-state-tree and I can't figure out how to get it working. Either this library is incredibly unintuitive or I'm just missing something obvious. I tried wrapping everything in `MST.types.optional()` to see if that makes a difference but nope.

The idea is that Orders store has many buy and sell orders. I want to create an empty store without any orders.

When I try to execute Orders.js, I get the following error:

```
Error: [mobx-state-tree] Error while converting `undefined` to `map<string, AnonymousModel>`: value `undefined` is not assignable to type: `map<string, AnonymousModel>` (Value is not a plain object), expected an instance of `map<string, AnonymousModel>` or a snapshot like `Map<string, { timestamp: Date; amount: number; price: number }>` instead.`
```

**order.js**

```
const MST = require("mobx-state-tree")

const Order = MST.types.model({
    timestamp: MST.types.Date,
    amount: MST.types.number,
    price: MST.types.number,
}).actions(self => {
    function add(timestamp, price, amount) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.price = price
        self.amount = amount
    }
    return { add }
})

module.exports = Order
```

**orders.js**

```
const MST = require("mobx-state-tree")
const Order = require('./order')

const Orders = MST.types.model({
    buys: MST.types.map(Order),
    sells: MST.types.map(Order),
}).actions(self => {
    function addOrder(type, timestamp, price, amount) {
        if(type === 'buy'){
            self.buys.add(timestamp, price, amount)
        } else if(type === 'sell') {
            self.sells.add(timestamp, price, amount)
        } else throw Error('bad order type') 
    }
    return { addOrder }
})
Orders.create()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to wrap everything as types.optional and provide a default snapshot for that.
Here's an example

```
const MST = require("mobx-state-tree")
const Order = require('./order')

const Orders = MST.types.model({
    buys: MST.types.optional(MST.types.map(Order), {}),
    sells: MST.types.optional(MST.types.map(Order), {}),
}).actions(self => {
    function addOrder(type, timestamp, price, amount) {
        if(type === 'buy'){
            self.buys.add(timestamp, price, amount)
        } else if(type === 'sell') {
            self.sells.add(timestamp, price, amount)
        } else throw Error('bad order type') 
    }
    return { addOrder }
})
Orders.create()
```

What types.optional do behind the scene is intercept undefined and replace that with your default value :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. It’s a bit of pita to remember to do but luckily models don’t change often.